# Multiple installs of windows

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have previously had dual installs of win7. 32bit / 64bit.

I have uninstalled / removed the harddrive that contained the 32bit now.

At startup I still get chose which Win7 you want to boot. Working one is seccond option, which is **really** annoying anyone know how I can fix / remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this via the `msconfig` utility.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 maintains loader entries in \bootmgr to modify this you can use bcdedit, a command line utility that is part of Windows 7. Small tutorial:

> [Modifying the Windows 7 boot loader](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/networking/?p=1709)

To remove the entry use:

```
Bcdedit /delete {boot loader identifier}
```

Where the identifier is the entry you no longer need. Just run bcdedit alone to see the entries in the boot loader section.

As an alternative you could use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) from Neosmart. It's essentially a graphical version of bcdedit. version 2 can be found on the forums, once you have registered, however 1.7.2 works fine in Windows 7.